# Disappearing child process

Tags: c++, exec, fork, pipe, dup2

I have this method:

```
int build_pipe_and_call(char **argv1, std::string cmd1, char **argv2, std::string cmd2, int conc) {
    std::cout << "Building Pipe...\ncmd1: " << cmd1 << "\n cmd2: " << cmd2 << "\n";
    int *pipefd = new int[2];
    if (pipe(pipefd) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "There was an error setting up the pipe.\n";
        return -1;
    }
    pid_t cpid1 = fork();
    std::cout << "First process forked, cpid: " << cpid1 << " - Process " << getpid() << "\n";
    switch (cpid1) {
        case -1:
            std::cerr << "There was an error forking the process.\n";
            return -1;
            break;
        case 0: // this is the part that isn't executing
            std::cout << "Dup2 return: " << dup2(pipefd[1], 1) << "\n";
            std::cout << "Process " << getpid() << " duped and about to exec.\n";
            execvp(cmd1.c_str(), argv1);
            std::cout << "Process " << getpid() << " about to exit.\n";
            _exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            pid_t cpid2 = fork();
            switch (cpid2) {
                case -1:
                    std::cerr << "There was an error forking the process.\n";
                    return -1;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
                    std::cout << "Process " << getpid() << " duped and about to exec.\n";
                    execvp(cmd2.c_str(), argv2);
                    _exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    if (conc) {

                    } else {
                        int status1, status2;
                        std::cout << "Process " << getpid() << " about to wait.\n";
                        waitpid(cpid1, &status1, 0);
                        waitpid(cpid2, &status2, 0);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    delete[] pipefd;
    return 0;
}
```

I've added the print statements solely for the purpose of debugging. However, when this method runs, this is what gets printed.

```
Building Pipe...
cmd1: cat
cmd2: wc
First process forked, cpid: 1454 - Process 1453
First process forked, cpid: 0 - Process 1454
Process 1453 about to wait.
Process 1455 duped and about to exec.
```

Process 1454, the first process forked, prints the message immediately after it's created. However, it never prints any of the messages from the switch statement, and never executes the specified program (in this case, cat). The process doesn't hang around as a zombie, it simply disappears As a result, the second child process hangs up and never actually does anything.

(also, just to add, I'm aware I haven't added all the appropriate error handling yet, function isn't complete yet).

Comment: `int *pipefd = new int[2];` really?

Comment: Could you give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? We don't know all the arguments you're passing, and I doubt that all this code is necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipeline ends when it detects the EOF and for this you must close the unneeded descriptors once you have dupped it (*in the childrens and the parent*):

```
close(pipefd[0]);
close(pipefd[1]);
```

Also, always check the return value of `execvp`, you may have an error in the argv's:

```
if (execvp(cmd1.c_str(), argv1) == -1) {
    // check errno here
}
```

In addition, be sure to end the argv with a *nullptr* as last element, and *argv[0]* must be the command itself. The prototype:

```
int build_pipe_and_call(char **argv1, std::string cmd1, char **argv2, std::string cmd2, int conc)
```

...makes me think you are not providing the first element (*argv[0] = cmd1*). You wouldn't need to give that extra value (*cmdX*) to function `build_pipe_and_call` if you have it in *argv*.

Remember that if `execvp` goes well, you'll never reach the subsequent code in your program, so you won't see some messages as you could expect:

```
execvp(cmd1.c_str(), argv1);
std::cout << "Process " << getpid() << " about to exit.\n"; // if execvp didn't fail, it's never reached
```

Also be carefull to use *std::cout* once you have dupped it, as @larpico [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26209317/4095830)

Answer (score 2):

You are not seeing the messages from the switch statement because they have been written to the pipe. Try replacing `std::cout` with `std::cerr`.

Comment: Daily reminder that I'm a moron. Thank you for that. Now the question changes to what I'm doing wrong with regards to the pipe.

Comment: @NickDell'osa: the answer to that is in [jaba10](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4095830/jaba10)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26209490/15168).